# Django: How to group queryset by timestamp

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these two models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
```

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

        class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["blog_id", "timestamp"],
                name="Timestamp per blog must be unique"),
        ]
```

Let's say the IDs of some of the blog is [1,2,3,4,5]

I want to query and group the tags in such a way that the results is grouped by timestamp.
an example output will be like

```
[
 {'timestamp': '2021-04-13 15:35:26+00:00', [title_of_blog_id_1]: "hello", 'tag': 'Hello',
 [title_of_blog_id_2]: "new title", 'tag': 'new'}
 {'timestamp': '2021-04-13 15:55:26+00:00', [title_of_blog_id_1]: "hello next", 'tag': 'next',
 [title_of_blog_id_2]: "new updated title", 'tag': 'UP'}
]
```

Explanation of the output:

I want a situation in which the Tags are grouped by the timestamp and for each timestamp, it fetches all the blog title and corresponding tag for that timestamp.

Comment: Do you work with the Django REST framework? This provides serializers that can handle this more effectively.

Comment: Yes I work with Django rest framework. How can this be achieved in DRF?